# Which issue is Dragon Magazine's Martial Monk in?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, product-identification

I have been looking all over trying to find out whatever I can about the Martial Monk class and what is different about it from a normal Monk.  The only thing I could find was that essentially you can choose from Fighter feats instead of Monk feats.  What issue of Dragon Magazine is the particulars of 'Martial Monk' in and how can I get a hold of the writeup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## *Dragon* #310

The variant class martial monk appears in Aug. 2003's *Dragon* #310 in Andy Collins's article "Variant Fist: New Monk Variants" on page 45. The issue remains available as [treeware](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012WVU1S) and [electronically](http://paizo.com/products/btpy7e8w). A martial monk gains the "[f]ighter bonus feat list to choose monk bonus feats (at 1st, 2nd, and 6th level)."

Ask the DM if this means that the monk "need not have any of the prerequisites normally required for these feats to select them" (like the feats Improved Grapple or Stunning Fist, Combat Reflexes or Deflect Arrows, and Improved Disarm or Improved Trip specifically listed on *PH* 41, and, therefore, allowing the martial monk to, for example, at level 1 take the feat Greater Two-weapon Fighting (*PH* 95) or the feat Shock Trooper (*Complete Warrior* 112)) *or* if the martial monk must still meet the prerequisites for these new fighter bonus feats added to the list of monk bonus feats by the martial monk variant.